# XCode Storyboard - View appearing in Landscape?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode4.3

Building an application which started as fairly simple, but now got pretty complicated. I am facing a strange problem. I am now using only storyboards to define all of my views. The problem I am facing is, some view-controllers in storyboard are appearing in Landscape mode and others in Portrait mode.

I know it won't make a difference in final application, but it is making it hard for me to design and visualize things. Has someone else faced this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click on the view in storyboards , click on the attributes inspector (third from the top left) in simulated metrics change the orientation to portrait

Comment: This confused me for a while, I couldn't find the "Simulated Metrics" section because I had my "View" selected instead of the "View Controller".  

Make sure that you have the correct node selected in the "View Controller Scene".   You'll want to select the "View Controller", not the "View" or some other item.

The "View Controller Scene" is the pane to the left of the view area (left of the graph paper grid).  It can be shown/hidden by clicking on the little grey arrow icon on the bottom left of the graph paper grid area.